# How to published a script on Script Gallery

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

How can I publish one of my scripts to the Script gallery so I can add it to any other spreadsheet I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See issue http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1599 . 
Otherwise, you can publish a script bu clicking Publish--> Publish to Gallery in the script editor. However, this has to go through an approval process and will be available to public and I've heard grouses of this not happening too soon.